# Move iframe into another HTML column

Tags: html

I need some assistance to move an iFrame section (which holds a google maps link) into a column next to another column that already exist in HTML. The map must appear next to the Name/Email/Subject/Message section as per the screen shot attached.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<section class="padding bg-grey" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="section-title text-center">Contact Us</h2>
            <p class="section-lead text-center text-muted">Send us your inquiry, we will help you and reply as soon as possible</p>
            <div class="section-body">              
                <div class="row col-spacing">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                        <p class="contact-text">You can send us something like a question or project, we are open 09:00 to 17:00.</p>
                        <ul class="contact-icon">
                            <li><i class="ion ion-ios-telephone"></i> <div>+27823300387</div></li>
                            <li><i class="ion ion-ios-email"></i> <div>vhs2digital@kodinger.com</div></li>
                        </ul>
                        <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=720&amp;height=200&amp;hl=en&amp;q=21%20Taurus%20Road%2C%20Sundowner+(VHS2Digital)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=19&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" style="border:none;" class="maps"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
                        <form class="contact row" id="contact-form">
                            <div class="form-group col-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-12 mt-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Send Message
                                </button>
                            </div>                              
                        </form>                         
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: Map image to move into new column]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why can't you cut and paste the iframe element where you want it?

Comment: What do you mean by "move"? What have you tried to solve this problem, where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: My solution below ignores the fact that something's wrong with your layout. You should see both of those columns on a single row since they total 12 units. You might start by reviewing the Bootstrap documentation and fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another column element. Right now you just have a gap in the second row following a 7-unit column (of 12).

```
<div class="row col-spacing">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
        <form class="contact row" id="contact-form">
            ...               
        </form>                         
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-5"><!-- NEW COLUMN WITH WIDTH TOTALLING 12 -->
        <iframe src="https://maps..." style="border:none;" class="maps"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the first thing I need to achieve is creating a form/div section, the size of the blank portion to the right of the input fields (name, email, subject and message).  Once I get that right, i can add the map in there.   What I'm finding is, that wherever I add a <div> or <form> section, it adds it below the other elements and I can't  seem to position it to the right of the "<form class="contact row" id="contact-form">" section.  I might have to sharpen up by reading the bootstrap documentation.